# How to get a list of embeded subtitles from a group of ".m4v" videos?

Tags: video, mp4

I have a relatively large group of ".m4v" videos that have various subtitles embedded in them.  I would like to create a list that showed me what subtitles are embedded in each of the ".m4v" videos.  Is anyone aware of an easy way for me to generate a list of available subtitles from each of the ".m4v" files?

Answer (score 1):

I dug around and found out how to do it using "exifTool.exe".

The command line would look like this,
exiftool -a -medialanguagecode *.m4v >SubtitlesList.txt